# How to add new field tab in prestashop product backoffice?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to add new field in prestashop product backoffice . This tab is same description tab.Please find attached screenshot what I need .

[image]
Thanks

Comment: you should contact a freelancer to get it done for you, as it is not an easy task. I will take over a lot of effort and no one can do it for you free

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop overrides their core (all their code files) every time you use the one-click-update in order to prevent developers to mess with their core.

Any modification on this page will be overridden on your next update unless you are willing to update the files manually with FTP and the database via PHPMyAdmin (or with MySQL workbench via remote connection) without overriding anything related to this interface.

I strongly advise you against this as you'll most certainly face incompatibility between your version and Prestashop core pretty quickly.

If you think your request is good for the whole community, you might try to pull a suggestion here: http://forge.prestashop.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Do not put to much hope on this as Prestashop team is quite busy.

If it's something specific to your shop, you'll need to hire a freelancer to as suggested by *Raghubendra Singh* in his comment. I'll add to his comment that it will need to be in a custom module. You might try to pull a proposal on this website: https://www.upwork.com/

If you do so, make sure that the developer you hire have a good experience both with PHP/MySQL and Prestashop itself (as it is a complex system). Even if you hire a developer from Filipino or India, you'll probably need to invest at least a thousand US dollars in order to have something sharp.

Also, please note that you'll need to hire the developer once more at least for every major update (by example 1.7.X => 1.8.X) to fix the incompatibility with Prestashop core.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use an addon. For instance, [this one](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/additional-information-product-tab/5070-product-tabs.html). 
It allows adding an unlimited number of tabs, some of them have a predefined structure (contact form or attachments). Others are changeable. So it's possible to add any content you need: additional pictures, video, text, etc.